# "The closest I've come to V_ing"

Tags: grammar

> The closest I've come to V_ing ...

It's a relative construction for sure. But I wonder how to analyze it :

Is it

> **The closest** I've come ____ to V_ing ...

Or

> **The closest** I've come to ____ V_ing ...

Edit: Now I think that this is not a relative construction. The clause "I've come to V_ing.." act as a complement to "the closest(thing)", not as its relative clause. Somebody confirms this for me?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to say. can you reword and clarify your question?

Comment: I want to know whether [the closest] is the object of [come] or [come to].

Comment: @JohnKraemer The question seems clear to me.  I'm not sure who close voted, but I don't think there's any reason to close a question like this.  *V-ing* is a placeholder for an appropriate verb in *-ing* form.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a relative construction with a gap directly following the verb in complement position.  However, it is somewhat unusual in that its head is a superlative adjective rather than a noun.

Superlative phrases with relative modification do not permit *wh*-relatives, only bare or *that*-relatives:

> *1a.* [ **the closest** <s>*that*</s> I've come ____ to quitting my job ]
>   *1b.* [ **the closest** *that* I've come ____ to quitting my job ]
>   *1c.* [ **the closest** **which* I've come ____ to quitting my job ]　←　**ungrammatical**

We can compare this example to the following non-relative sentence:

> *2a.* I've come **this close** to quitting my job.

This should help illustrate the position of the gap.

The relativized examples *1a* and *1b* are functionally similar to noun phrases (although *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* on p.1169 says "there is no plausible reason to propose that the [...] phrases they head are NPs").  They can be, for example, the subject of a sentence.

Let's illustrate this by putting *1a* into a complete sentence:

> *3a.* [ **The closest** <s>*that*</s> I've come ____ to quitting my job ] is when my boss told me I had to wear that rubber chicken suit.

The optional presence of *that* and the correspondence to the non-relative *2a* are both arguments against the alternative analysis you give at the bottom of your question.  You were right the first time when you called it a relative construction.